# Can a SQL Server BAK file from Amazon S3 be directly restored to a Snowflake Dataware house?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-s3, data-warehouse, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to restore a Bak File from S3 to Snowflake, is this possible ?
I do understand that the SQL Server is a traditional RDBMS while snowflake is columnar so the process would be very difficult, Is there a native way to do it ?

Comment: Is there something you already tried that you could share?

Answer (score 2):

No, SQL Server BAK files are not just a typical RDBMS vs. columnar format, but they are also compressed and encrypted very specifically for a SQL Server...and even the SQL Server version that they were created with.  You would need to either restore this to SQL Server and then BCP the data to flat files, or use a BAK recovery tool and then exporting the data to flat files.  And, then you can import the flat files into Snowflake.